# Change Google Map marker icon

Tags: java, android

I wrote this code in `onMapReady` and call a function to change Google Map icon but it does not work.
here the code:

```
  public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lng)
                .icon(getBitmapDescriptor())
                .title("Marker in Mashhad"));
}

 private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor() {
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.round_accent, null);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found this and it`s work :D
Replace the function with "BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource"

```
   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bazaarteh_logo_text))
                .title("Marker in Mashhad"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lng, 12.0f));
```